# Cannot get audio input of Soundblaster HD working

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, creative

I have a Creative Soundblaster HD which has a RCA output and a RCA/Phono input. I have connected my smartphone with the audio input of the USB soundcard and the RCA output of it is connected with my Hifi system. I can play sound from my PC on the sound card so the output is working. I also checked the cable.

In the sound settings of Windows 7 in the tab record the Line-In appear as not available. Also in Audacity I can't use the Line-In. I upgraded the firmware of the sound card and also reinstalled the driver. I also disabled the multistream feature.

In the entertainment console the Line-In is activated.
[image: entertainment console]

Now I ran out of ideas. It has worked in the past but now it isn't working anymore. What settings do I have to change to get this working?